# crontab extract cron expression

Tags: bash, shell, cron

When i do **crontab -l**, I can see all my jobs

```
56 12 3 2 * /usr/bin/python3 /home/pi/Saqib/RaspBerryPiAdhan/www/commands/player.py "https://server6.mp3quran.net/akdr/001.mp3" "Office Ustairs speaker" >> .error.log  2>&1 # Al-Fatiha - [Verses 7]
56 12 * * * /files/python3 /home/pi/Saqib/RaspBerryPiAdhan/www/commands/player.py "https://server6.mp3quran.net/akdr/001.mp3" "Office Ustairs speaker" >> .error.log  2>&1 # Al-Fatiha - [Verses 7]
31 18 3 2 * /usr/bin/python3 /home/pi/Saqib/RaspBerryPiAdhan/www/commands/player.py "/static/media/azan5.mp3" "Office Ustairs speaker" # prayer_isha
```

anyway I can just extract the "Expression" only?

I need outout like this...

```
56 12 3 2 * 
56 12 * * * 
31 18 3 2 *
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This should work:

```
crontab -l |awk '{NF=5}1'
```

Here you are telling awk that number of fields in each line is 5 , which leads to print of first five columns.

Comment: i see...whats the "1" after }?

Comment: see https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/63891/what-is-the-meaning-of-1-at-the-end-of-awk-script

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following

```
crontab -l | sed 's/  *\/.*//'
```

which substitutes everything (`.*`) after a slash (which needs to be escaped, `\/`), including it and the spaces before it (`*`) with the empty string.

As indicated in the comments, this solution is not robust at all, as it relies on the format peculiar to the example in the question.

Comment: The expression for "every four hours" is `0 */4 * * *`. A regular mail alert may be `0 8 * * * echo "Time to wake up" | mail me@host`. Both causes this command to fail

Comment: Oh, well, I don't know the format of crontab's output, so my question was based on the example shown in the OP. However, thank you for pointing this out.

Answer (score 0):

Cut should work too.

```
crontab -l | cut -d ' ' -f-5
```